# How to configure maven to use latest or predefined Spring version / hibernate Version

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I am new to Maven and I use STS Eclipse to build spring-maven application. My problem is when I create new spring project by default it adds spring 3.1 and servlet 2.4 version to pom file but I want to add spring 4.2.6 and servlet 4 version. I can edit pom manually but is there any way to configure the maven setting so that it uses the version I provide them.

Comment: I assume you are using an archetype which is a kind of template...so best would be to change the template.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Spring Boot reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-dependency-management) :

> Each release of Spring Boot provides a curated list of dependencies it
>   supports. In practice, **you do not need to provide a version for any of
>   these dependencies in your build configuration as Spring Boot is
>   managing that for you**. When you upgrade Spring Boot itself, these
>   dependencies will be upgraded as well in a consistent way.

The only versions you need to set is the Spring Boot version itself :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

and, if you use some, the versions of libraries unknown from Spring Boot.

If you want to check which version of a dependency is installed by Spring Boot look at [the list in the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions).